# Targeting Locations in content seen as keyword dumping

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords, content

Lets say I have the following page about catering it reads something like this:

We do Catering in All mayor cities in Australia including Perth, Sydney, Melbourne..etc.

Lets say the user clicks the link `Sydney` the following page: `catering-sydney.php` opens up

**The Content**

***We do food catering in all suburbs of Sydney including:***

```
    Abbotsford, Aberfeldie, Airport West, Albion, Alphington, Alphington, 

Altona, Altona Meadows, Altona North, Ardeer, Armadale, Arthurs Seat, Ascot 

Vale, Ascot Vale West, Ashburton, Ashwood, Aspendale, Aspendale Gardens, 

Attwood, Avondale Heights, Avonsleigh, Badger Creek, Balaclava, Balnarring,

 Balnarring Beach, Balwyn, Balwyn North, Bangholme, Batman's Hill, Baxter, 

Bayles, Bayswater, Bayswater North, Beacon Cove, Beaconsfield, Beaconsfield 

Upper, Beaumaris, Beenak, Belgrave, Belgrave Heights, Belgrave South, Bellbird,

 Bellevue, Bellfield, Bend of Islands, Bennettswood, Bentleigh, Bentleigh East,

Berwick, Bittern, Black Rock, Blackburn, Blackburn North, Blackburn South, 

Blairgowrie, Blind Bight, Bonbeach, Boneo, Boronia, Box Hill, Box Hill North, 

Box Hill South, Braeside, Braybrook, Briar Hill, Brighton, Brighton East, 

Broadmeadows, Brookfield, Brooklyn, Brunswick, Brunswick East, Brunswick West, 

Bulla, Bulleen, Bundoora, Bunyip, Burnley, Burnside, Burwood, Burwood East, 

Cairnlea, Calder Park, Caldermeade, Camberwell, Campbellfield, Cannons Creek,

 Canterbury, Cape Schanck, Cardinia, Carlton, Carlton North, Carnegie, Caroline

 Springs, Carrum, Carrum Downs, Catani, Caulfield, Caulfield East, Caulfield 

North, Caulfield South, Chadstone, Chelsea, Chelsea Heights, Cheltenham, 

Chirnside Park, Christmas Hills, Chum Creek, Clarinda, Clarkefield, Clayton,
```

**My Question**

Can this be seen as keyword stuffing? I dont like the above but I need to let the users know which areas we cover! What alternative option do I have here? Will best practice be to create a page for each and every suburb mentioned above?

Comment: Have you looked into using mark-up from schema.org? There may be a neater way of doing what you want other than listing areas. Otherwise, it might look like keyword stuffing. I am not too keen on how sites like yours handles these things. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I agree with you, Im also not keen on how this site handles things Im just trying to find a better alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...in all suburbs ...  ...I need to let the users know which areas we
>   cover...

If you write "in all suburbs", you already let users know, that all suburbs are covered, so no need to list them all one by one.

if you even list them all, no one will read such bunch of continuous text.

The best way to show, which area is covered by your service, is to show a Google map with the colored polygon for these areas.

The best way to include it into the site is:

- Create an own Google map with this polygon (Googla Maps -> my maps -> create map)
- implement it with structured data into the site, going the way: https://schema.org/Offer -> https://schema.org/eligibleRegion -> https://schema.org/GeoShape -> https://schema.org/polygon